# multiple where conditions with linq and list

Tags: linq, entity-framework, conditional-statements, where-clause

I am attempting to use the following code to do an update on a table with entity framework.  The where statement will only work if I remove the and, either side of the and will bring results, but the and results in a null.  I know that the value I am searching for exists.

```
foreach (fdd element in FddList)
{
    var slist = context.ResidenceFDDs.ToList<ResidenceFDD>();

    ResidenceFDD fddtoupdate = slist
        .Where(s =>
            s.StName.Contains("Adrienne") &&
            s.StNum == element.addressnumb.ToString())
        .FirstOrDefault<ResidenceFDD>();

    fddtoupdate.Comments = "Comment newly added.";

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You can chain them instead if you want to debug. e.g. slist.Where().Where() or slist.Where(); slist.Where()

Comment: Are you sure that there is an entry that matches both criteria? Maybe you have entries that match one or the other but not both.

Comment: Duh.  You think I wouldn't test this to make sure that the thing matched come on . . . . . . it totally doesn't match.  I forgot about upper and lower case in c# vs Sql.  This was my problem all along.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `.toString()` then use as below

```
  ResidenceFDD fddtoupdate = slist.Where(
    s =>
        s.StName.Contains("Adrienne") &&
        s.StNum == element.addressnumb.ToString())
    .FirstOrDefault<ResidenceFDD>().AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: I could also remove the tostring() and not use the asenumerable? It doesn't seem to like using asenumerable in that statement.